# Do more files increase compile time in Swift?

Tags: ios, clean-architecture

I am currently using CLEAN Swift iOS architecture for a fairly large iOS app (http://clean-swift.com), it's based on Uncle Bob’s Clean Architecture. It really does reduce the size of the view controllers however there are a LOT of files for each scene (or screen). A typical screen will have files such as: ViewController, Presenter, Interactor, Router, Configurator. We are also using a separate storyboard per view controller - each storyboard only has one view controller. There are also many worker files that do various api calls. The Swift compile time is fairly slow, but in my memory I'm pretty sure it always was (even before we changed our architecture from MVC to CLEAN). However some coworkers are starting to question if this architecture is what is causing the slow compile times. My question is, does using more files increase the compile time? Would MVC compile quicker? Also, what about storyboards? Is this bad practice using one per view controller?

Comment: Well I will say yes more file will take more time to compile.As far as MVC it is just separation of business from presentation and make the look and feel of your code better.But that will still require you to create more model classes so still more files will be created.And you can use  multiple views on one view controller instead of creating one for each .

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. More files increase compile time, some more than others.
A way to reduce the compile time, is to remove storyboards and then do the ui in code, or make your storyboards as reusable as possible.
In my experience, clean architecture works best with an all-code, code base, as you reduce the number of view files, if done correctly.
Although another question you should ask yourself, is the slightly increased compile time, more beneficial in terms of having more readable, maintainable, and testable code, rather than messing with the ever increasing controllers of the MVC? And MVC might not even decrease your compile time, as you might end up having larger storyboards (in most cases). 
And for the last question. Yes one storyboard per controller could be considered bad practice, but only if these storyboards aren't reusable.